# Deserialize Json to List(of Integer)

Tags: json, vb.net

I'm trying to deserialize some Json to a .Net class. I'm having a problem with the contacttypeidlist field. 
How can I change the Json to get this to work?

I am receiving the following error:

*Cannot convert object of type 'System.String' to type'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Int32]'*

**Json**

```
[
    {
        "fullname": "bob smith",
        "email": "bob@test.com",
        "phone": "555-5555",
        "onsite": "true",
        "contacttypeidlist": "[1,2,3]"
   }
]
```

**Deserialize code**

```
 Dim oSerializerSort As System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer = New System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer()
 Dim lobjSiteContactsList = oSerializerSort.Deserialize(Of List(Of SiteContact))(lstrSiteContactsJson)
```

**SiteContact Class Definition**

```
Public Property fullname As String
Public Property email As String
Public Property phone As String
Public Property onsite As Boolean
Public Property contacttypeidlist As List(Of Integer)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `"contacttypeidlist"` property in your JSON is just a simple plain string. So make sure you respect this in your model:

```
Public Property contacttypeidlist As String
```

On the other hand if your JSON looked like this (notice the missing double quotes around the value):

```
"contacttypeidlist": [1,2,3]
```

you could have used an integer array in your VB.NET model.

If you have no control over the original JSON and cannot fix its format so that the `contacttypeidlist` property represents an actual integer array instead of a string then you have to perform the deserialization in 2 steps: first deserialize the original JSON into a structure with a string property. And in a second step deserialize this string property to an integer array.

Comment: I need to have a list of integers, not a simple string.  How to change my json to fix this?

Comment: If you need to have a list of integers then you need to fix your JSON. I have updated my answer to illustrate how your JSON must have looked for this to work. If on the other hand you have no control over the format of the JSON string then you have to do this in 2 steps. The first step is to deserialize the original JSON into the structure with a String property and then deserialize your string property to an integer list. Of course this would be a terrible waste. The best thing to do is to simply fix your original JSON.

Comment: How would I build this on the client side?  This is how i do it now: `myObject.contacttypeidlist = "[1,2,3]";`

Comment: If by *client side* you mean javascript, then simply get rid of the double quotes so that you have an actual integer array instead of some string value: `myObject.contacttypeidlist = [1,2,3];`

Comment: That works.  Now I need to figure out how to take a comma separated list of strings(integers) and convert it to that format [1,2,3]. Is that another post?

Comment: You mean in javascript? This deserves another post but here's a hint: you could use a conjunction of the [`split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) and [`parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) functions in order to get an array of integers from a comma separate integers encapsulated into a string variable.